# Restrict dragging of marker to a particular country

Tags: android, google-maps-markers, google-maps-android-api-2, android-studio-3.0

Can I restrict the dragging of marker in maps to a particular country? I don't want user to drag the marker outside India because of some features of my application.

Comment: The difficult part may depend on how precise you need to model the border.  Ultimately you'll have to perform a test on the position against some boundary using LatLngBounds/Builder as @Mauker suggests.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can restrict where the marker may be placed.

Take a look at the [GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap.OnMarkerDragListener). You'll see that this interface has three methods.

- `onMarkerDrag(Marker marker)`
- `onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker)`
- `onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker)`

First, you'll have to listen for the `onMarkerDrag` events. Do that by setting the listener to your map instance, like:

```
mMap.setOnMarkerDragListener(new OnMarkerDragListener() {

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragStart(Marker marker) {
        // ...
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDragEnd(Marker marker) {
        // Use this method to detect when the user stopped dragging the marker.
    }

    @Override
    public void onMarkerDrag(Marker marker) {
        // Listen to this method to check the marker position.
    }
});
```

That method will be called every time you try to drag the marker somewhere.

Once you detect that event, you may continuously check the marker position by calling [`myMarker.getPosition()`](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#getPosition()), and compare it to some boundary. See the [LatLngBounds](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds) class, and its [Builder](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/LatLngBounds.Builder) for more info on that.

If the marker ever crosses that boundary, make it "undraggable" by calling the marker [setDraggable](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Marker.html#setDraggable(boolean)) method, like below:

```
myMarker.setDraggable(false)
```

And then, on the `onMarkerDragEnd` method, make it draggable once again, otherwise the user won't be able to drag the marker after he crosses the boundary:

```
myMarker.setDraggable(true)
```